# ListView specify verticalScrollbarPosition in xml

Tags: android, android-layout

Having `ListView` but I can customizing it only by modifying `layout.xml` (it's our system  design restriction). I need specify value for `verticalScrollbarPosition` in such manner:

```
<ListView
...
android:verticalScrollbarPosition="right"
... >
</ListView>
```

It is possible using `android:verticalScrollbarPosition` instead of `ListView.setVerticalScrollbarPosition()`?

**ADD**

Or suggest another way to specify position of the scrollbar. Not necessarily based on the `verticalScrollbarPosition`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to setup vertical scrollbar position in xml layout. You can check this by looking at sources.